# Flutter GridView footer (for indicating load with infinite scrolling)

Tags: gridview, scroll, dart, infinite-scroll, flutter

I have a GridView which works pretty smooth. I use the grid in the context of infinite scrolling where more items are loaded via a REST API whenever scrolling is close to the bottom. No problems here.

However I want to be able to display a loading indicator at the bottom of the grid. This Widget **should span all columns in the grid**, but should still be a part of the scrollable content.

I am new to Flutter and lost as how to achieve this.

My (working) GridView is instantiated like so:

```
return new GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: _COLUMN_COUNT),
  controller: widget.scrollController,
  itemCount: widget.items.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return new _ItemView(item: widget.items[index]);
  },
);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Wrap SliverGrid by CustomScrollView:

```
return new CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
  new SliverGrid(
    gridDelegate: yourGridDelegate,
    delegate: yourBuilderDelegate,
  ),
  new SliverToBoxAdapter(
    child: yourFooter,
  ),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in which manner you are building your layout, regardless, I know it is a little different than what you were thinking of, but this sounds to me like a good use case for [`CircularProgressIndicator`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html).

Note in my case it keeps loading because my `snapshot.hasData` is always `false`. Whenever your data is loaded it will replace the `ProgressIndicator` with whatever data you originally intend to inject inside your widgets.

[image]

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("GridView Test"),
        ),
        body: new FutureBuilder(future: _getAsyncStuff(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
              return new GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return new Card(child:
                    !snapshot.hasData ? new CircularProgressIndicator(
                      strokeWidth: 0.8,) : new Text("Snapshot data#$index")
                    );
                  });
            })

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not what he was asking for. He was referring to the loading indicator for infinite scrolling in the footer.

Answer (score 0):

What @najeira mentions is correct and if you still want to keep the "controller: widget.scrollController" property, the CustomScrollView widget supports it:

```
CustomScrollView(
  controller: widget.scrollController,
  slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverGrid(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate( (c,index){return Widget();},
                                              childCount: widget.list.length),
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      )...
```